# date_format expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface/ Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on boolean in

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

```
<?php
include "dbConnect.php";
function getTimeTable($tutorID, $parseDate) {
    //'$parseDate'
    global $con;
    $today = date ( "Y-m-d" );
    $time_table_res = mysqli_query ( $con, "SELECT BeginTime, EndTime FROM TimeTable WHERE TutorId = '$tutorID'" );
    $timetable = array ();
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows ( $time_table_res );

    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $time_table_res, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {
            $begin_time = DateTime::createFromFormat ( 'Y-m-d g:i a', $parseDate . " " . $row ['BeginTime'] );
            $end_time = DateTime::createFromFormat ( 'Y-m-d g:i a', $parseDate . " " . $row ['EndTime'] );

             while ( $begin_time <= $end_time ) {

                $fdate = date_format($begin_time, 'g:i a'); 
                array_push ( $timetable, $fdate );
                $begin_time->add ( new DateInterval ( 'PT30M' ) );
            } 
        }
    }
    return $timetable;
}
?>
```

Hi,

I am very new to php and would appreciate any insight available. I am trying to create a scheduling system, but I have really been struggling with the time formats and keeping them from outputting in military time.

These are the two lines in particular that are giving errors

$fdate = date_format($begin_time, 'g:i a');

$begin_time->add ( new DateInterval ( 'PT30M' ) );

Answer (score 1):

If the date string supplied to [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) does not match the format provided in the first parameter, it will fail to create the date object and will return `false`. This is the boolean referred to in your error message "Call to a member function add() on boolean".

You need to correct the date format or the date string so they match. The easiest way to debug this is to call `var_dump($parseDate . " " . $row ['BeginTime'])` and see in what way the string doesn't match the expected format.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that out!

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeZone, string given' in C:\wamp64\www\2016tutorme\tutorme\getTimeTable.php on line 22
( ! ) Exception: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeZone, string given in C:\wamp64\www\2016tutorme\tutorme\getTimeTable.php on line 22
Call Stack